# how to copy I/O not just redirect (Windows and Linux)

Tags: windows, linux, shell, script, batch

I have a simple call command

```
call calabash -D sim.xpl >test.txt 2>&1
```

and this redirects into test.txt, how do I do both redirect into a file and allow it to show up in the prompt?

(I could use the command for both linux and windows)

(use case: tar-ring a backup takes a while and watching the the verbose output allows me to keep an eye on it, and kill it early if needed, rather than to open a large file or wait until its done)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`tee`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

```
call calabash -D sim.xpl 2>&1 | tee test.txt
```

Comment: that just copies to multiple files (learned something new) but is it possible to keep the IO in the prompt and copy it to a file?

Comment: @jtzero, did you try? What multiple output files do you see in Ignacio's command line?

Comment: `tee` outputs its input to stdout. Just don't do something silly like redirecting it somewhere else.

Comment: `call calabash -D sim.xml 2>&1 >( tee test.txt )` may do what you want.  Due to buffering methods you may not see the prompt until you respond to it.

Comment: @all sorry I commented before he posted the command just the link. and based on the link description it says multiple files. but yes it works thanks Ignacio!

Comment: Sure, if you pass multiple files to `tee` then it will copy the output to multiple files. But also to stdout.