# Is there a way to get real time stdout and stderr from a process spawned by psexec on the same streams (pipes) as psexec

Tags: command-line, io, jenkins, psexec

My question is very close to this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/649550/redirect-output-of-process-started-locally-with-psexec) with an additional constraint related to time-outs

I'm using Jenkins to start some automated testing and then to capture the stdout (and stderr) of the running tests.  As I've answered there I have determined how to get the stdout and stderr to display once the tests have finished, however the method I describe prints everything in the terminal when the process ends it's execution, not as it goes.

My problem occurs because my test jobs are on a 15 minutes timeout (the test script can take 1.5 or more hours to run) if Jenkins does not see any activity on the output pipe.  I do not wish to substantially increase this timeout because the tests can hang.

**Is there a way to get the stdout and stderr streams of the child process created by psexec in the terminal window that psexec is running under in real time?**

psexec is started by a batch script on the test machines, not being used over a network.

I've considered running psexec with the -d flag and piping the child process output to a file and then just running a loop in the batch script that waits for the process to finish, this seems to be rather more a hack and should be an option of last resort.

runas is not a good alternative as Jenkins needs to know when the test scripts are finished.  I could do similar to what I've mentioned above with the PID and a wait loop, but that's still a hack.

I am also wondering if it might be possible to simply pass psexec's IO streams to the child and patch the output straight back through to Jenkins that way but I have no idea how to do this.